# How to delete the bar nearby line number in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I am using Notepad++ and want to change its style.

[image: bar]

What should I do to delete the bar boxed nearby line number? I can't find the associated option.

Comment: `I am using notepad++ to develop Operating System.` - wow!

Comment: I am using notepad++ to develop Operating System. =/

Comment: Create a feature in the Operating System to delete the bar boxed nearby line number.

Comment: Got something to contribute, guys, or did you just feel like piling on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Settings menu
2. Preferences
3. Editing
4. Folder Margin Style -> None

[image: Where to find folder margin style setting]